# Can one hear the *material* of a drumhead?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, inverse-problems

"Can one hear the shape of a drum?" is a well known problem, originating from [Kac, 1966](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum), that questions whether an (idealized) drum head is completely specified by its spectrum.  That is: is the Dirichlet boundary $D$ uniquely determined given the complete eigenspectrum $\lambda_i$ for the Helmholtz equation?:

\begin{cases}
\Delta u + \lambda u = 0\\
u|_{\partial D} = 0
\end{cases}

While there are exceptions, apparently the spectrum *is* unique for a 2D convex drumhead (Zelditch, page above), so relatively strong statements can be made without considering high dimensional systems.

I'd like to know: **"Can you hear the *material* of a drumhead?"** I'm interested in a similar equation with an additional term, $V(\mathbf x)u(\mathbf x)$.  For purposes of the analogy, Kacs problem asks whether the boundary of an ideal drum is determined by the sound; I'm asking to what extent the drum head itself can be characterized if there is some varation in material or thickness.

Specifically, I'm interested in how well $V(\mathbf x)$ is determined based on all eigenvalues $\lambda$ *and* eigenfunctions $u(\mathbf x)$ for the following:

\begin{cases}
\left[\Delta_{\mathbf x} + \lambda + V(\mathbf x)\right]u(\mathbf x) = 0\\
u|_{\mathbf x \rightarrow \infty} = 0
\end{cases}

As the original problem is a particular case of this one ($V(\mathbf x) = 0$ over $D$, $V(\mathbf x = D) = \infty$), so strictly speaking the answer is 'not completely'.

As a side note, this question arose from research in non relativistic quantum mechanics, and can be stated as: how similar are two potentials if they share the same eigenspectrum *and* eigenfunctions?  If the discrete spectrum is matched, does this imply the continuous spectrum is also?  I've already posted a similar question in Physics SE.  Thanks!!

Comment: But if you know a eigenfunction and the according eigenvalue, you get $V(x) = -(\Delta_x u(x) + \lambda)/u(x)$ where $x \ne 0$. And if $u(x) = 0$ on some open set, you have $V(x) = -\lambda$ there.

Comment: By the way: a different material (i.e. density) would enter the diffusion term: $\operatorname{div}(\rho \, \nabla u)$ instead of $\Delta u$.

Comment: I have doubt this will work in general. If we ignore the condition
$u|_{\mathbf x \rightarrow \infty} = 0$ and replace $V(x)$ by $\psi(x,t)$
where $\psi(x,t)$ is a solution of the [kdV equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation), the spectrum will be independent of choice of $t$ (I'm not $100$% sure about the normalization constant, you have to check it yourself). This sort of isospectral behavior is the key behind the [inverse scattering transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_scattering_transform) method for solving some non-linear PDEs.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks for the lead... I'll have to take a look at the inverse scattering theorem.  It can't work in general (the original problem is an unsolvable particular case) - do you have any idea what information you *can* say, or limits thereof?

Comment: Sorry, my understand of IST is pretty minimal. It is one of the thing I wish to learn but failed.

Comment: @gerw you're right.  This is a simplified version of my problem that turns out to be *too* simple.  I'd like to modify to post the actual problem, but it's different enough that I may have to ask another question...